# Vscode fails to resolve tensorflow fuctions in editor

Tags: python, tensorflow, visual-studio-code

I have codes like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
mapp = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda x : x.reshape([-1]+list(x.shape[2:]), data))
```

No problem happens when running this code, but in vscode editor, the resolved result for `nest` and `map_structure` is Incomplete. And autocomplete also fails for tensorflow.

[image]

Additionally, for all other tensorflow functions, it shows same error. The IntelliSense for tensorflow only have data type and `Tensor` class and `Variable` class, etc.

But for other modules like `numpy`, everything works fine. And if in Jupyter in the same python env, it works fine even for tensorflow.

So I think the problem should be in the vscode, but have no idea where it should be exactly.

Any idea about this problem is appreciated!

**Version**

```
vscode : 1.75.1
python : 3.8.10
tensorflow : 2.11
```

**More Info**

I checked the extension installed as
[image: Python]

[image: Plance]

and I can show the resolve result for tensorflow and numpy as
[image: tf]

[image: np]

Comment: First of all, I have to remind you that your code is missing `)` at the end. Second, you need to paste the error message after you running the file. I copied your code and [get the intellisense](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3WPC.png). This makes me wonder whether you have installed the Python and Pylance extensions?

Comment: Thank you for the response and sorry for the mistake in the code. First, no error happens when run the file so there is no error message. Then, I checked the extensions installed and show them in the post. So the extensions seem to be fine, but the results for numpy and tensorflow, which are installed in the same path, are different.@MingJie-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many times and found a possible solution.

This may be because your **Python Language Server** is not defined. So Pylance was not enabled.
You can add the following codes to your `settings.json` to enable it:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance",
```

Comment: But I have tried both with and without this setting, and nothing changed. Since this error is only detected with respect to tensorflow currently, the problem might be witrh tensorflow, or vscode. But I did nothing to tensorflow compared to two days before when everything was fine. The only thing I have done related to this problem is updating vscode yesterday, but that can not explain the different results for tensorflow and numpy. So confused.

Comment: If I delete this line of code, I will encounter the same error as you. The version I am using is 1.75.1. You can try to rollback the [version of VsCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_74).

Comment: @XIAOXUFENG By the way, have you  reloaded vscode after changing the `settings.json`?

Comment: Yes, every time the `settings.json` was changed, I tried by reloading vscode. But results are same @MingJie-MSFT

Comment: I'm sorry I can't provide more help. This works for me. Of course, you can also try to change Pylance to Jedi, this may work.